# Fixed navigation after scroll and CSS classes toggle

Tags: jquery, scroll, css-position

I created a simple web page layout. You can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/1129/

I managed to create the fixed navigation after the user scrolls down to a certain point. What I have been struggling to achieve is to assign a `class="active"` to each list item as the user moves from section to section.

When the navigation gets fixed on top of the viewport is when I want the `class="active"` added to the first list item

```
<li>
   <a href="#something" class="active">something</a>
</li>
```

and then as I move on down the page, the `class="active"` is removed and then added to the next list item.

I have found some plugins that do exactly that but the truth is I haven't managed to integrate them into my project. Also, because of the fact that I am very new to jQuery, I don't understand the code.

I also found this http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/3/ which again had a difficult time integrating..

So, what is your advice?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/1131/) to include a new block of javascript that handles the highlighting of the menu options based on the example fiddle you gave.

The block I added is:

`$(".main-content section").each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll - hdr + 20) {
        mn.find('a.active').removeClass('active');
        mn.find('a').eq(i).addClass('active');
    }
});`

This loops through each of the sections that you have menu options for and checks the scroll of the window. After substracting out the height of the header and adding some padding back in, that number is compared to the position of the element on the page. If the scroll is greater than the position, then mark the menu element as active.

Keep in mind that since the sections are rather small, the last couple sections may not highlight since you can't scroll down that far.

Comment: This works great and I can say that I understood what you did there.. Kinda :| The only problem is that when I click the first list item, it scrolls to the right position but it does not get highlighted. It needs a pixel or two of scrolling down. Why is that? About the height of the sections I am aware of that.

Comment: When you click the "services" link, the page scrolls to the spot just before the "main-nav--scrolled" gets applied to the menu causing the background color to change. If you inspect the "services" link, you can see the "active" class is on the element, but since the nav isn't dark, the white highlight does not show up.